# Remove component from palette

Tags: delphi-7

I've been using an ActiveX control for VNC Viewer support in a legacy application for a few years now. The ActiveX control is called `Smartcode ViewerX VNC Viewer`. After a bit of trouble connecting to one of our systems, I decided to update to the latest version (which was available on the Smartcode website). This didn't resolve the issue and moreover had a nag dialog because I had forgotten our 1-year upgrade license had lapsed.

After uninstalling the latest version I would now like to start again but try as I might, I cannot re-install the previous version because there is already a `TCSC_ViewerControl` component on the ActiveX palette. How do I remove this so I can start again?

[image: Stray control in ActiveX palette - how to remove?]

When I select control, there is no option to delete it.

#### UPDATE

I tried moving the component to a separate page (ie. removing it from the `ActiveX` page). Then I tried deleting this page, but I get the message:

```
A page must be empty before it can be deleted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed this component into the `dclusr70` package. You will need to open up that package file (open its .dpr file) and remove the units that relate to this file. Then compile the package and install it again.

Comment: Thanks, David. Do you mean manually edit `C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Lib\dclusr.dpk`? How do I recompile `dclusr` afterwards?

Comment: I think I've worked it out. (1) Manually edit `dclusr.dpk` to remove the references to VIewerX, (2)  Component > Install Packages and open `Borland User Components`, (3) Click `Edit` and then `Compile`, (4) Re-install component.